# Photo viewer without scrolling effect

Tags: photos, pictures

I'm looking for a photo viewer that skips from one picture to another without the scrolling effect, just like the desktop picture viewer does. Anyone knows an app that does it?

Comment: How would you want to scroll between photos? Or are you just after a slideshow?

Comment: Yeah, just a plain slideshow, no transition at all.